# How can I plot the session close from today?

Tags: pine-script

I've created a simple script to draw in a gap range, however, in this iteration, it won't plot the gap for the next session until the market actually opens, so you can't do any pre-market pondering. I've been working around this by making the variable a user input and inputting the close value manually, but I'd prefer to automate this.

[image: Where it is vs where I want it]

Here's the script in it's current form:

```
//@version=4
study("Mastering the Gaps", overlay=true)

//Color
var color yellow = #FFFF99

//User defined variables
gapSize = input(defval = .20, title = "Gap width")
labelOffset = input(defval = 20)

//Data fetching
sClose = security(symbol = syminfo.tickerid, resolution = "D", expression = close[1], lookahead = true)

//Gap calculations
uGap = sClose + gapSize
dGap = sClose - gapSize

//Draw gap lines
line.new(x1 = bar_index -1, y1 = uGap, x2 = bar_index, y2 = uGap, extend = extend.both, color = color.new(yellow,50), width = 1)
line.new(x1 = bar_index -1, y1 = dGap, x2 = bar_index, y2 = dGap, extend = extend.both, color = color.new(yellow,50), width = 1)

//Gap Labels
var label uGapLabel = label.new(bar_index, uGap, "Upper Gap Range", style=label.style_label_down, color = color.new(yellow, 50))
var label dGapLabel = label.new(bar_index, dGap, "Lower Gap Range", style=label.style_label_up, color = color.new(yellow,50))

//Label location
label.set_xy(uGapLabel, bar_index - labelOffset, uGap)
label.set_xy(dGapLabel, bar_index - labelOffset, dGap)
```

I've attempted this code as well, however I just get a study error saying the resolution '1600' is invalid.

```
sClose = security(symbol = syminfo.tickerid, resolution = '1600', expression = close[1], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
```

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to accomplish. You can't know the gap for the current session before the market opens, because you need the current session open price for that. So I don't know what you mean by pre-market pondering.

Comment: I'm not plotting the gap range, It's simply a plot line of the closing price, the gap is merely a calculation of a valid gap range to trade, as in, as long as the gap is this big, it's a valid gap to trade.  Therefore, I don't need the market open, the open price is not part of my script.

Comment: To simplify further, I don't want the data point marked by the X, I want the data point marked by the Arrow

Comment: ok, so you simply want a line for the last close, that's drawn automatically?

Comment: I want to use my existing script, in it's current form, with a different data point.  The variable I want to change is ``sClose``.  I want that variable populated by the close marked by the arrow in the picture, not by the current variable indicated by the X in the picture, which is the close from the previous day.

Comment: Which ticker did you use in your example?

Comment: I used SPY, curious why it matters?  This will work on any chart.

Comment: It doesn't matter, but I always like to try code on the same ticker from the example.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure, but maybe something like this:

```
//@version=4
study("Mastering the Gaps", overlay=true)

//Color
var color yellow = #FFFF99

//User defined variables
gapSize = input(defval = 5, title = "Gap width")
labelOffset = input(defval = 20)

// var float sClose = na

var line l1 = line.new(na, na, na, na, xloc=xloc.bar_time, extend = extend.right, color = color.new(yellow,50), width = 1)
var line l2 = line.new(na, na, na, na, xloc=xloc.bar_time, extend = extend.right, color = color.new(yellow,50), width = 1)

//Data fetching
[sClose, sTime] = security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", [close[1],time_close[1]])

if not barstate.isrealtime and barstate.islast and barstate.isconfirmed
    sClose := close
    sTime  := time

//Gap calculations
uGap = sClose + gapSize
dGap = sClose - gapSize

//Draw gap lines
line.set_xy1(l1, sTime,   uGap)
line.set_xy2(l1, sTime+1, uGap)

line.set_xy1(l2, sTime,   dGap)
line.set_xy2(l2, sTime+1, dGap)

//Gap Labels
var label uGapLabel = label.new(bar_index, uGap, "Upper Gap Range", style=label.style_label_down, color = color.new(yellow, 50))
var label dGapLabel = label.new(bar_index, dGap, "Lower Gap Range", style=label.style_label_up, color = color.new(yellow,50))

//Label location
label.set_xy(uGapLabel, bar_index - labelOffset, uGap)
label.set_xy(dGapLabel, bar_index - labelOffset, dGap)
```

Comment: Not too shabby!  I was able to make it work with just 2 lines of that code. (The if not barstate.etc and the line below that)  I also gave your full script a copy/paste.  Either way, if you activate the extended hours session, it wants to plot the end of the extended session, which seems odd.  I was pretty sure the "D" resolution didn't include extended sessions, and if you do replay, it actually works properly whether you have the extended session displayed or not.  I'll have to give the documentation another read to understand these barstate variables better.